# Bootstrap3 Datepicker - Count Active dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap3 Datepicker and trying to count the number of active dates and return them to the console. My current project is to count the days "worked" and return them, therefore I need to use a multiple date selector (Range wont work). For example, I work MWF, I want to select 3 days in that week and return a count of 3. In the future I would also like to know how to add the active days to an array.

The default events, http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html, don't seem to have anything related to the activation / deactivation of a date. The only event that seems to make sense is changeDate. This allows me to count, but also counts when I deactivate the date. I then tried to trigger a removal of count using clearDate, but that does seem to have any relationship with deactivating a date.

```
var count = 0 ;
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    multidate: true
});
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {   
    count += 1;
 console.log(count);
});
$('#datepicker').on('clearDate', function() {   
    count -= 1;
    console.log(count);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an object is passed to the event that contains the information you need. Try the following:

```
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {  
    // e.dates is an array
    console.log(e.dates.length);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How did you go about finding out? Was this documentation or did you use the developer tools?

Comment: @TalisLazdins I got it from the docs. At the top of the page that you linked is a small snippet of code that shows passing the 'e' variable, and the items below the snippet are objects contained within 'e'. For example, e.date is the latest date picked in a multidate picker.